# Construction of infinitesimal Lorentz transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, inertial-frames

I'm following the book from Greiner on relativistic QM and I got two questions here:

[image]

1. In (3.36b) where does the last expression come from? From which we get delta = delta + omega_nu^sigma + omega^sigma_nu hence the antisymmetric form (3.36a).
2. How (3.36a) implies in there being six non-vanishing omega^{mu nu} and why the others vanish?

Comment: Please don't use images/screenshots but use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [quote function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead.

Comment: @TobiasFünke tyvm i didn't know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You just need to use the Kronecker delta using $\delta^\mu_\nu a^\nu = a^\mu$ and the obvious extension to quantities with more indices. In that case we clearly have $\delta^\mu_\nu\delta^\sigma_\mu = \delta^\sigma_\mu$ and we also clearly have $\delta^\mu_\nu \Delta\omega_\mu^{\phantom\mu\sigma}=\Delta\omega_\nu^{\phantom\nu\sigma}$. The last term is exactly analogous. Putting all these together you get the last expression in (3.36b)
2. One $4\times 4$ anti-symmetric matrix $M_{\mu\nu}$ necessarily has only six independent entries. For starters, anti-symmetry $M_{\mu\nu}=-M_{\nu\mu}$ implies that all entries in the diagonal must be zero. This follows because $M_{\mu\mu}=-M_{\mu\nu}$ must imply $M_{\mu\mu}=0$ if $M_{\mu\nu}$ has real or complex entries. This already eliminates four entries of the matrix, which must vanish.

   Now all entries below the diagonal are determined in terms of the entries above the diagonal because of anti-symmetry. But above the diagonal, you have exactly $3$ entries in the first row, $2$ entries in the second row, $1$ entry in the third row, and no entry at all in the last row. In total, you have $6$ entries which determine the matrix completely.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In (3.36b) where does the last expression come from?

It comes from expanding the product and dropping the terms with more than one factor of $\Delta \omega$.

> 2. How (3.36a) implies in there being six non-vanishing omega^{mu nu} and why the others vanish?

A 4-by-4 matrix has 16 elements.

The four diagonal elements are all zero, since they have to be equal to the negative of themselves.

The remaining 12 elements are off the diagonal, but the 6 elements above the diagonal have to equal the negative of the respective 6 elements below the diagonal. So there are only 6 independent elements.